# Getting this Software Error on trying to update the parameters in bugzilla-4.0.4

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, bugzilla

Getting this Software Error on trying to update the parameters in bugzilla.

```
Error in tempfile() using data/params.XXXXX: Could not create temp file data/params.BFQJE: 
Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 293
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

> Could not create temp file data/params.BFQJE: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 293

This is pretty self-explanatory. You need to adjust permissions for the `data/` dir.

It's relative to bugzilla installation dir as one may learn by reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that every content in the bugzilla directory have been given permission accordingly.You can run this command in the bugzilla directory:

```
 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
 find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
 find . -name \*.cgi -exec chmod 755 {} \;
 find . -name \*.pl -exec chmod 755 {} \;
 find . -name \*.sh -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

after that run the checkout.pl

```
 ./checksetup.pl
```

lastly you need to restart your webserver(for me i use apache)

```
  service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ran checksetup.pl as root and it did not fix things, check your access control lists (acl) on the files.

I had this same problem and while the permissions looked right at first glance, there were access control lists in play that were causing problems.

```
drwxrwx---+ 8 root www-data 4096 May  5 12:23 data
```

The plus (+) at the end of the permissions indicates that an access control list is active. Running getfacl showed that the www-data group did not have write permissions.

```
getfacl data
# file: data
# owner: root
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::r-x
... other acls
```

Once I removed access control lists from the bugzilla install checksetup.pl was able to set things straight.

```
sudo setfacl -bR bugzilla/
cd bugzilla
sudo ./checksetup.pl
```